# Is IOS Scroll View is Scrollable in Storyboard while Designing? Not Runtime in Simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview, storyboard, interface-builder

In Storyboard i have view controller, inside i have a scroll view. question is scrollview is not scrollable while design time (UIKit). is it like that ? though, it works fine in simulator. [image: Inage]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have setup your constrains correctly, sure, you can scroll in Storyboard / Interface Builder.

Simply select any subview of the scroll view, and you can scroll just like you scroll anything else (such as this web page).

Here I have a stack view with several labels and buttons, in a scroll view:

[image]

I have the stack view selected and, as you see, I can scroll the content:

[image]

---

**Edit** - example *without* stack view:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Storyboard Source**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="20037" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES">
    <device id="retina4_0" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="20020"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="System colors in document resources" minToolsVersion="11.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="R32-dA-683">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="vD2-wr-GKn" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="nx6-KC-Ism">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="568"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <scrollView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="iRw-uR-kHf">
                                <rect key="frame" x="29" y="80" width="262" height="200"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="These are NOT in a stack view." textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" numberOfLines="0" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="2gt-3M-hxU" userLabel="TopLabel">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="12" y="12" width="238" height="57.5"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.66847345069999997" green="0.96944552660000005" blue="0.92393370939999997" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="displayP3"/>
                                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="24"/>
                                        <nil key="textColor"/>
                                        <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                    </label>
                                    <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="XQI-7T-dgO">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="12" y="89.5" width="238" height="34"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="0.1857388616" blue="0.57339501380000002" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                        <inset key="imageEdgeInsets" minX="0.0" minY="0.0" maxX="2.2250738585072014e-308" maxY="0.0"/>
                                        <state key="normal" title="Button 1"/>
                                    </button>
                                    <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Label 1" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" numberOfLines="0" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="xM5-9u-L9O">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="12" y="143.5" width="238" height="29"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.66847345069999997" green="0.96944552660000005" blue="0.92393370939999997" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="displayP3"/>
                                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="24"/>
                                        <nil key="textColor"/>
                                        <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                    </label>
                                    <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="8Xy-ME-rrn">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="12" y="192.5" width="238" height="34"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="0.1857388616" blue="0.57339501380000002" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                        <inset key="imageEdgeInsets" minX="0.0" minY="0.0" maxX="2.2250738585072014e-308" maxY="0.0"/>
                                        <state key="normal" title="Button 2"/>
                                    </button>
                                    <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Label 2" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" numberOfLines="0" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="cmo-bX-Wha">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="12" y="246.5" width="238" height="29"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.66847345069999997" green="0.96944552660000005" blue="0.92393370939999997" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="displayP3"/>
                                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="24"/>
                                        <nil key="textColor"/>
                                        <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                    </label>
                                    <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="oJQ-EN-Pc2">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="12" y="295.5" width="238" height="34"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="0.1857388616" blue="0.57339501380000002" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                        <inset key="imageEdgeInsets" minX="0.0" minY="0.0" maxX="2.2250738585072014e-308" maxY="0.0"/>
                                        <state key="normal" title="Button 3"/>
                                    </button>
                                    <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Label 3" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" numberOfLines="0" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="qbm-Ls-5bH">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="12" y="349.5" width="238" height="29"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.66847345069999997" green="0.96944552660000005" blue="0.92393370939999997" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="displayP3"/>
                                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="24"/>
                                        <nil key="textColor"/>
                                        <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                    </label>
                                </subviews>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstItem="XQI-7T-dgO" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="2gt-3M-hxU" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="20" id="1JB-jn-Y1A"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="8Xy-ME-rrn" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="2gt-3M-hxU" secondAttribute="trailing" id="5xk-GB-AXw"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="qbm-Ls-5bH" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="2gt-3M-hxU" secondAttribute="leading" id="Fvr-yK-lDT"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="200" id="Ihy-yc-MRl"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="cmo-bX-Wha" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="8Xy-ME-rrn" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="20" id="Iin-6N-3gO"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="xM5-9u-L9O" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="XQI-7T-dgO" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="20" id="J9M-zb-NzA"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="qbm-Ls-5bH" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="2gt-3M-hxU" secondAttribute="trailing" id="Kde-rB-mb0"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="2gt-3M-hxU" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="QXL-qb-619" secondAttribute="top" constant="12" id="Ntt-xH-QjE"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="8Xy-ME-rrn" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="xM5-9u-L9O" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="20" id="Pwf-RD-jiR"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="qbm-Ls-5bH" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="QXL-qb-619" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="-12" id="Svr-fK-RCS"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="cmo-bX-Wha" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="2gt-3M-hxU" secondAttribute="trailing" id="Ybg-lo-eZf"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="xM5-9u-L9O" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="2gt-3M-hxU" secondAttribute="leading" id="cG2-4v-Nhr"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="8Xy-ME-rrn" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="2gt-3M-hxU" secondAttribute="leading" id="ckZ-hn-bLA"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="XQI-7T-dgO" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="2gt-3M-hxU" secondAttribute="leading" id="ddl-OY-kTY"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="oJQ-EN-Pc2" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="2gt-3M-hxU" secondAttribute="trailing" id="eLH-pR-rdE"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="2gt-3M-hxU" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="QXL-qb-619" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="12" id="ePZ-Uj-mk4"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="XQI-7T-dgO" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="2gt-3M-hxU" secondAttribute="trailing" id="hIQ-js-aEj"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="qbm-Ls-5bH" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="oJQ-EN-Pc2" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="20" id="jNx-LZ-ynL"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="oJQ-EN-Pc2" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="2gt-3M-hxU" secondAttribute="leading" id="kw8-Ms-6YK"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="2gt-3M-hxU" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="Qga-bs-KPf" secondAttribute="width" constant="-24" id="pNe-nW-Yzd"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="xM5-9u-L9O" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="2gt-3M-hxU" secondAttribute="trailing" id="pUa-cV-nnJ"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="cmo-bX-Wha" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="2gt-3M-hxU" secondAttribute="leading" id="qNj-RD-4sl"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="2gt-3M-hxU" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="QXL-qb-619" secondAttribute="leading" constant="12" id="qXU-fl-OTt"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="oJQ-EN-Pc2" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="cmo-bX-Wha" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="20" id="ucE-MC-AnG"/>
                                </constraints>
                                <viewLayoutGuide key="contentLayoutGuide" id="QXL-qb-619"/>
                                <viewLayoutGuide key="frameLayoutGuide" id="Qga-bs-KPf"/>
                            </scrollView>
                        </subviews>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="OhM-Cg-QZj"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="iRw-uR-kHf" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="OhM-Cg-QZj" secondAttribute="top" constant="80" id="EH1-J3-Hha"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="iRw-uR-kHf" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="OhM-Cg-QZj" secondAttribute="leading" constant="29" id="LKa-pv-cz5"/>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="iRw-uR-kHf" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="29" id="xW2-T3-k3K"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="1GU-I7-lw5" userLabel="First Responder" customClass="UIResponder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="-789.375" y="214.43661971830986"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
    <resources>
        <systemColor name="systemBackgroundColor">
            <color white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
        </systemColor>
    </resources>
</document>
```

Comment: Can we do this as without using Stack View ?

Comment: @AnkurPipaliya - of course... as  long as your constraints are setup correctly. See the **Edit** to my answer.

Answer (score -1):

The Interface Builder (with which you're building XIBs and Storyboards) is not "live", you cannot interact with the UI elements like you can with the "live" mode of SwiftUI Previews. This also means you cannot scroll a scroll view.